# URL rewrite in sub folder using .htaccess

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting, subdirectory

I am trying to implement URL rewriting in my PHP application. Can someone share a step by step procedure of implementing URL rewriting in .htaccess.

In my application I want to implement following URL

www.domain.com/shop/shop.php?shopname=myshop&sh=1

to

www.domain.com/shop/myshop

i use the follwing

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /shop/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /shop\.php\?shopname=([^\s&]+)&sh=([^\s&]+) [NC]

RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ shop.php?shopname=$1&sh=$2 [L,QSA,NC]*
```

It shows the url like www.domain.com/shop/myshop

But not pointing to www.domain.com/shop/shop.php?shopname=myshop&sh=1

Comment: How are you going to map id? you don't have it in the URL `www.domain.com/shop/myshop`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can do what you want with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]*)&name=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/shop/shop.php$ /shop/$2?id=$1
```

The RewriteCond check for a query string of the correct format and extracts the values. $1 = the ID and $2 = the name.

The RewriteRule rewrites a URL of the correct format to the new format, inserting the name and id parameters from the RewriteCond.

Comment: This will never work for a couple of reasons. Those are backreferences also